# Absolute and relative positioning in different breakpoints

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I have problems with two badges that are supposed to stand in the middle of the edges of a product card. The main problem occurs when i change devices (mobile design works, but tablet/desktop doesn't).

**Desired mobile design outcome**

[image]

**Desired tablet/desktop design outcome**

[image]

**Current mobile design outcome -satisfactory except the triangle on the left badge**

[image]

**Current tablet/desktop design outcome - bad**

[image]

So, as you can see. The purple and green badges move out of the borders of the product card. And it gets worse when i change the resolution from lets say 1440px to 1200px. They keep moving with the screen shrinking, not staying within the card. I would like to achieve the same result as in mobile screen; the badges should follow the card, not go outside of it.

I am using Tailwind CSS.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="This is an example of a meta description."
      />
    <title>refurbed homework</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,100&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body class="font-poppins">
    <div class="bg-gray-100 justify-center w-full min-h-screen p-6">
      <div
        class="bg-white text-gray-700 flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-lg w-full md:w-72 items-center static mx-auto">
        <div
          class="p-1 md:p-4 rounded-md bg-refurbed-400 top-3 left-4 md:left-1/3 absolute text-center opacity-95">
          <span class="text-white font-medium text-xs md:text-lg relative top-0">RECOMMENDED</span>
        </div>
        <div
          class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-green-500 top-1 right-4 md:right-1/3 absolute text-center">
          <span class="text-white font-medium relative top-3">-40%</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex md:flex-col p-4">
          <img
            class="m-4 h-32 w-20 md:h-36 md:w-24"
            src="./assets/images/spacegray.jpg"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center mt-4 md:mt-0">
            <h2 class="text-center p-4 text-gray-500 font-bold order-2 md:order-1">
              iPhone 8
            </h2>
            <div class="hidden md:space-x-4 md:flex md:items-center md:order-2">
              <div class="color-circle bg-yellow-400"></div>
              <div class="color-circle bg-red-600"></div>
              <div class="color-circle bg-gray-600"></div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="p-4 font-bold text-3xl text-green-500 order-3">225€</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to make badges' direct parent's position relative

Comment: I tried to change it around with relative/absolute but it doesn't work that way. If i chnage it to relative it destroys my mobile screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following div that contains the content to `positiong: relative`, afterwards put the recocmended and "%" div sections inside the div and set them to `position: absolute` and position them with left and right as you wish.. for the recommended I assume it will require a few pixels to the left like `"left: -24px"` and vice versa. This should work on mobile as well and fix the styling problem you are having, if all the content is inside the white div containing the mobile sale info.
[image]

for now they push out too much on the big screens because the parent div has a lot of width, rather set them inside the tiny div containg the info and it should fix your problem.